# Is it possible to use libx264 to convert H264 raw data to a image(PNG/JPEG) without ffmpeg?

Tags: rtp, x264

I received some video data via RTP / RTSP / SIP, the data is encoded by H264 and sent by a IP camera. I would like to convert H264 keyframe data into a picture and analyze whether it contains faces. I do not want to use FFMPEG such a huge library, just use libx264 and opencv can do it? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible. X264 can not decode (it is a h264 encoder only). It also can not encode jpeg/png. Ffmpeg is what you need. If it is too large, custom compile including only the features you need. And static link so unused functions are striped out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer